# file.flush() doesn't work in Python after writing binary data

Tags: python, file, buffer, pickle, flush

I'm exploring files in Python, and I have this example:

```
from pickle import *

l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
f = open('file.txt', 'r+b')  # open file to write the list into (IT IS INITIALLY EMPTY)

dump(l, f)  # write the list l into f

f.flush(). # apply changes to file without closing it

print(load(f)) # < HERE I can't read the data because f is empty as it initially was
```

Why doesn't `flush()` apply my written text to `f`?

Comment: Try `f.seek(0)` after flushing to set the stream position to the start of the file? After flushing the file the position is still at the end of the stream, flushing doesn't do anything but write the stream buffers

Comment: @IainShelvington oh heck, forgot about that. Works now, ty